# How to convert string in 'DD/MM/YYYY' or 'YYYY-MM-DD' into date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got a string here which needs to be converted into date but the problem is that it could either be in 'DD/MM/YYYY' or 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

I've already tried convert which only works for one of the two formats but not both:

```
declare @string nvarchar(255) = '2019-05-21'

declare @table table (date date)

insert into @table
select convert(date, @string, 111) as date

select * from @table


declare @string nvarchar(255) = '21/05/2019'

declare @table table (date date)

insert into @table
select convert(date, @string, 103) as date

select * from @table
```

Both of the above solutions result in an error is I use the other format.

Is there a way to get a string converted to date regardless of what format it is in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `try_convert()`:

```
insert into @table
    select coalesce(try_convert(date, @string, 111),
                    try_convert(date, @string, 103)
                   ) as date
```

`try_convert()` returns `NULL` if the conversion fails.  In that case, the conversion will move on to the next pattern.  With `coalesce()`, you can have as many different formats as you like.

Comment: Note (for OP, not you, Gordon) that this still allows ambiguous dates - is 1/2/2019 Jan 2nd or Feb 1st? I'd highly recommend some sort of data cleaning upfront and store dates in the database as dates, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TRY_PARSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [PARSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to parse the date literal using a specific culture.

The second format `YYYY-MM-DD` is an unambiguous date format for the "new" date types like `date` and `datetime2`. It's not affected by the `DATEFORMAT` setting like `datetime`.

This means you only need to find one culture that can handle the first format. All of the following queries will return the same value :

```
select parse('21/05/2019' as date using 'en-GB')
-----
2019-05-21

select parse('2019-05-21' as date using 'en-GB')
-----
2019-05-21

select try_parse('21/05/2019' as date using 'en-GB')
-----
2019-05-21

select try_parse('2019-05-21' as date using 'en-GB')
-----
2019-05-21
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are on SQL 2012 and above, you can use the FORMAT function.

The signature of this function is - `FORMAT (value,format[,culture])`

Example: `SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'dd-MM-yyyy') as date` and in your case `SELECT FORMAT(CAST(<str_value> as DATE), 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Comment: The question is how to *parse* the string into a date

Comment: How? To parse a string you need CONVERT or PARSE. FORMAT does the opposite

Comment: `FORMAT` takes a non-`varchar` value and converts it to a `varchar` value in a specific format. If you pass a `varchar` to `FORMAT` is literally does nothing with it. As per the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) it expects a Numerical or Date and Time data type.

Comment: The first argument passed to FORMAT is a date object. The answer has been updated.